# remove decimal Place in SQL

Tags: sql

Code :

```
days_between("Created Time","Locked Time")*24
```

Result table :

```
Avg Response time (Hours)   
2.91                        
6.00                        
9.13                        
3.65                        
1.17                        
0.00                        
0.77                       
32.47
```

The table above is the result i get after the code but currenlty I want to remove all decimal place right before i get this result with the days_between("Created Time","Locked Time")*24  i am using, So how can I do this. I tried to use cast and round () but is not working. Can someone help out. Thank you

Try code:
days_between("Created Time","Locked Time")*24  , 0) AS INT ) AS Response_Time

Comment: What is the expected result for the rows in your example?

Comment: It's not clear what your asking or to what database platform this refers, it sounds like you're asking to `round()` your values? What have you researched so far? `days_between` is product-specific.

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data I guess:

```
with t(d) as ( 
    values (2.91), (6.00), (9.13), (3.65), (1.17), (0.00), (0.77), (32.47)
)
select d, cast(d/24 as decimal(5,2)) from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar query running on MSSQL, and I can do it as:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 a.SizeBytes AS originalValue
                ,COALESCE(a.SizeBytes, 0.00) / (1024 * 1024) AS defaultOperation
                ,CAST(COALESCE(a.SizeBytes, 0.00) / (1024 * 1024) AS INT) AS withCast
                ,FLOOR(COALESCE(a.SizeBytes, 0.00) / (1024 * 1024)) AS withFloor
                ,ROUND(COALESCE(a.SizeBytes, 0.00) / (1024 * 1024), 0) AS withRound
FROM filesUploaded a
WHERE a.SizeBytes > 0
```

Resulting in:
[image: Query Result]

Note that I limited my query to the top 10, for speed generating this example, as my table contains millions of rows.

Also my starting value is integer, so I had to add the decimals in order to be able to see decimals. Probably you don't need to do that as the average should already have decimals, but in my case just dividing returned an integer result for the division without using the `COALESCE` before dividing.